# Auto complete parentheses in print statement

Tags: visual-studio-code

I always used PyCharm for Python coding, but wanted to give VSCode a shot and really like it so far.

The only thing where I am struggling with now is when I auto complete pri (with <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd>), it only give me "print" instead of "print()".

Is there any option to enable this?

Answer (score 2):

Add this code to Visual Studio Code's settings > python `settings.json`:

```
"python.analysis.completeFunctionParens": true,
```

Answer (score 1):

go to file > references > python > Auto Complete: Add Brackets

Answer (score 0):

type this in search of settings in vs code

Python › Auto Complete: Extra Paths

click on edit in settings.json

then add this in settings.json below this
("editor.suggestSelection": "first")

"python.analysis.completeFunctionParens": true,

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).